# Migrate from mcrypt command line tool to openssl (or other)

Tags: linux, openssl

I am currently in the process of migrating away from the "mcrypt" command line tool. The main reason for this is, that mcrypt is not available for alpine docker images. Also it seems that mcrypt in general is not very maintained anymore and hence moving to openssl seems like a good choice to me.

As I have hundreds of gigabytes that are encrypted with mcrypt, I would need to find a way to decrypt those files with openssl. Historically mcrypt was used in bare mode and I would need to be able to handle those files.

What I tried so far:

```
echo "test" > test.txt

# Encrypt with mcrypt. The algorithm and the mode are actually the defaults
mcrypt -b -a rijndael-128 -c cbc -k "test" < test.txt > test.enc.mcrypt

# This fails due to "bad magic"
openssl enc -in test.enc.mcrypt -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:test -d

# This fails due to "bad decrypt"
openssl enc -in test.enc.mcrypt -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:test -d
```

I also read that aes-256-cbc might be used, but it yields the same result.

Anyone has some idea on how to decrypt those previously encrypted files?

Comment: The safer approach would be to decrypt using mcrypt and encrypt with openssl.

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, I am aware. But the sheer amount of data makes this impractical to me. This makes me need some kind of backwards compatibility. New data is going to be encrypted in a more modern way.